# Whats is the use of logout button in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, login, logout

Following are some steps I follow when I logout from Stack Overflow.

1. Keep focus on username this will show me following popup.
   [image: Logout in website]
2. After click of logout following screen appears.
   Working great :)
   [image]
3. Now I want to login again I click on login.
   Then following screen appears.
   [image: Login again]
   Again great movement for me.
4. But the website don't allow me to login with new email id it automatically consider previous email ID as my login but this time I want to login with new id why should I login with same id that I logout just.
   Confused with this behavior.
   What is solution if I want to login with other user ID.

Comment: So you have more than one user account?

Comment: Merge the accounts and you won't have a login problem. Simple as that.

Comment: We have single internet machine for two IT guys both want to access stack account simultaneously , In this case what is the solution.

Comment: Use different browser (that you never used before to visit Stack Overflow), or browse in private mode. The login credentials are stored in local storage (lower level than cookies)

Comment: try clearning your web history.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that not really solution why logout is not working??

Comment: @Lucifer clearing browser history and all other stuff.. Many time..

Comment: @IAMHERE, can you tell me, how you clear your history ?

Comment: @IAMHERE logout means "I want out of here". It does not mention coming back, so nothing is broken. It's like leaving the house: when you log out, you leave the house and close the door. All good. When you come back, the door is smart enough to open for you without need to unlock it manually.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd its like leaving house and lock it with some password and when come back in house it should ask me for password other wise I am invalid user as simple as that. Where is authentication??

Comment: @lucer first of all clearing history will not clear password as what you want to say. but I am using Chrome not IE and from settings I can clear "History" as well as password information.

Comment: @IAMHERE didn't write the system and agree it might appear to be "too smart" especially in shared computers. Guess it's also related to how your OpenID provider works. Stack Exchange does not store your password anywhere, it just store OpenID token and let the provider handle the actual authentication. Assuming you're using Google, try logging out in there too and untick "remember me".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Even if I click "Remember me" so what is that mean I cant log out at all. And one more is that while not approach like gmail.

Comment: @IAMHERE you do log out, if you visit any page other than the login you are not logged in.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd please tell me use of log out in website then.

Comment: @IAMHERE it's explained nicely in the answer to the other question I just linked to: *When you log out of SO, you are ONLY discarding a cookie that SO pays attention to. SO does NOT send you to google, not does it perform a logout from google*.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that's what I said I am not even login open ID Gmail then why stackoverflow till showing my login.

Comment: @IAMHERE it's issue with Google, not Stack Exchange.If you are really so troubled by all of this, create new account using Stack Exchange OpenID then ask to merge your old account into that new account and remove the Google OpenID from "my logins".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd same happen with yahoo account please try yourself. you may found it.

Comment: Don't edit the title it won't help. Instead you better off starting new question asking what's the use of logout button instead of beating this dead horse.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if I raised same issue thee its again duplication why we are not continuing with same post??

Answer (score 1):

The OpenID credentials used to log in are sometimes cached by the provider. If you watch the address bar while clicking on your login provider, it does an elaborate dance of redirects, ultimately ending in you being logged in without ever using a password.

I'm not saying it's the best system (especially for shared computers), but it is what it is.

Comment: lets its allows me to login without authentication but is this write ??. If right then there is no use of password and login you just login once use it forever.

Comment: @IAM  When you log out, the cache will expire after a day, then you will have to log in.

Comment: You already used the password when you logged into the OpenID provider (Google, for example). There is no need to enter it again as long as your OpenID authentication is still active.

Comment: @George That's what I was trying to say. Thanks :)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I agree if I already login then I doesn't need to login again , but if I logout then that mean its self I don't need any thing login information. Log out means Log out out what. Then why there is logout button better remove it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins and Undo please tell me use of logout then??

Comment: @IAMHERE Try this: Log out of SO, then log out of your OpenID provider (Google, etc). Next time you try to log in here, you will be prompted for your password.

Comment: @Undo as you day cache expire in one day but last 7 days I unable to logout.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins what is SO??

Comment: SO = "StackOverflow"

Comment: I am not using any openID for browser. Not working.